# How can I have 3 months displayed on datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker

Using datetimepicker, how can I show 3 months? With datepicker it would be using `numberOfMonths: 3`, like this:

```
$(".dateField").datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii',
    todayBtn : true,
    numberOfMonths: 3, 
    showCurrentAtPos: 1
});
```

But with datetimepicker its not working:

```
$(".datetimeFields").datetimepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii',
    todayBtn : true,
    numberOfMonths: 3, 
    showCurrentAtPos: 1
});
```

Comment: Which datetimepicker are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine for me and showing 3 months.

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    showCurrentAtPos: 2,
    changeYear: true,
    autoclose: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<input type="text" class="datepicker" /><br/>
<style>
    .ui-datepicker {font-size:60%; }
</style>
```

Or you can go through

solve your datetime issue copy this code in notepad as html and run on browser your issue is resolved here and tick this solution as usefull .

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        </head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/i18n/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon-i18n.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>


<body>
<div class="example-container">
        <p>Set the min/max date numerically:</p>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="datetime1" id="datetime1" value="" />
        </div>                  

<script>
    $('#datetime1').datetimepicker({
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii',  
       numberOfMonths: 3

    });
</script>

    </div>  


    </body> 
</html>
```